# phalcon order by related model column

Tags: mysql, phalcon

I want to get records from table `users` ordered by column `viewed` from related table `profiles`. The point is that I want to do it in model-way.

Simply I want to write query below and get models as a result.
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN profiles ON users.id = profiles.user_id ORDER BY profiles.viewed DESC
```

Comment: You can write your own SQL queries like this or any type by using the models Manager. http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Manager.html

Comment: Here is a link with examples http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html

Comment: I tried to do it with modelsManager, but it seems that something is wrong with phql with JOIN. I mean, when I execute simple SELECT query I can do ->toArray() on the resultset, but when I try to achieve the same on query with JOIN I get Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row with really weird construction. Please also note, that example from http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model_Query.html doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I resolved my problem. I just get all users, and I added to my reslut array key "viewed", then I do custom multisort and I got what I want. Maybe this solution is not as good as it could be using single query, but it's enough. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

see my example

```
$Users = \User::query()
        ->leftJoin('UserDependence')
        ->where(implode(" AND ", $conditions))
        ->bind($parameters)
        ->orderBy("User.id DESC")
        ->bindTypes([
            "email" => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            "active" => Column::BIND_PARAM_BOOL,
            "tags"  => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR
        ])
        ->execute();

    $paginator   = new PaginatorModel(
        array(
            "data"  => $Users,
            "limit" => 10,
            "page"  => (int) $this->request->get("page")
        )
    );
```